# Using Metaplex mpl-token-metadata program can I restrict minting to a collection nft?

Tags: metaplex, nft, collection

I am creating a Metaplex collection following [this doc](https://developers.metaplex.com/token-metadata/collections#associating-nf-ts-to-collection-nf-ts). I want to mint NFT and add to this collection. But I want to restrict who can add NFT to the collection NFT to a certain address. How can I achieve this?